# Is there a way to map a function that will read a list of strings and concatenate them into one big string?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Can I get a quick explanation on how I would concatenate a list of strings into one string using map? I was trying to use intercalate but I realized that this is used to combine lists and not strings. i.e. [[char]] instead of [String]

```
type InformationList = (String , [String] )

concatenateList :: String -> [InformationList] -> String
concatenateList n cs = do
  let [informationlist] =  intercalate " " cs
  let toWrite = n ++ [informationList]
  return toWrite
```

I updated this so that you can see the code I've been working with. It is saying that [[char]] is not the same as [informationlist] but that should be the same as [String]

Comment: `String` is an alias for `[Char]`. You can concatenate with a separator via `intercalate "," ["a", "b", "c"]` to get `"a,b,c"`

Comment: `type String = [Char]`, so `String` is an alias of `[Char]`. This thus means that `[[Char]]` is equal to `[String]`.

Comment: @everyone I've update my question, so hopefully its more thorough. My apologies.

Comment: Please do not use `return`. It does not do what you think it does, it is a monadic function.

Comment: @hawkeye: It is not clear what your `concatenateList` is supposed to do. What is `InformationList`?

Comment: How do you want to produce a string out of the `InformationList`? How do you want to represent such `(String, [String])` instance?

Comment: Never use `do` and `return` if you are not working inside a monad. Never use `[x]` as a list variable: `let [x] = exp` roughly means "please crash my program if `exp` is a list whose length differs from 1; otherwise define `x` to be the single element in the list". This is not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

A `String` is a **list of `Char`s**. A `String` is a type alias defined as:

```
type String = [Char]
```

If you want to concatenate a list of `String`s without any separators, you can use **`concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]`**:

```
Prelude> concat ["foo", "bar", "qux"]
"foobarqux"
```

In case you want to insert a **string** as delimiter, you can use [**`intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:intercalate):

```
Prelude> import Data.List(intercalate)
Prelude Data.List> intercalate "," ["foo","bar","qux"]
"foo,bar,qux"
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `unwords :: [String] -> String` which basically does what `intercalate " "` does, but with a more specialized signature and directly from the Prelude.